# SQL Server 2005 collation for restored backup file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server using the `Latin1_General_BIN` collation. System databases also use this collation.

Now, I have user database backup file. I restored to some database which now uses the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation.

The problem is recompiling stored procedures. SQL Server is throwing errors like

> @some_variable not declared.

The question is: how do I solve this as database has several hundred stored procedures and tables.

Do I need to rebuild system databases?

Thanks .. 
Atul

Comment: Your two choices are 1) rebuild to system databases or 2) change the variables and literals to match case.

Comment: I want to achieve this in minimum time, So re-installation and restore again is not option as DB restore will take almost 3 hrs.

Comment: I am trying to rebuild the system databases..